# UI for Handset & Tablet

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I want to make an app that runs both in handset & Tablet as shown in figure:

[image]

- This custom listview would contains around 200 items, its title & description can be loaded from SQLite
- For loading 200 images should I use blob in SQLite or from the drawable folder,which would be a better approach ?
- I read the android [documentation Supporting Tablets & Handsets](http://my.fit.edu/%7Evkepuska/ece5570/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64/sdk/docs/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html), it states that we should use fragments. So can anyone recommend me some tutorials to use fragments
  that fits my question ?

I am new to it so any type of help is appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: Search on internet about fragment and you will get lots of examples.

Comment: any suggestion for the 2nd point?

Comment: My personal opinion is to store them in drawable if you don't have a problem with .apk size. The reason is you need extra efforts to convert from blob to image each time and if some one delete the database then your images get deleted.

Comment: So you mean to say, using blob apk size can be minimized?

Comment: I don't have clear idea about that but logically it should be as it stores data in binary. And other reasons mentioned are straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **Master/Detail Flow** is what you need. Luckily it's already built into Android Framework.

Creating a new project, when you reach this page, instead of selecting Blank Activity, select the third template, that is Master/Detail Flow.

[image: Master detail flow]

The best way to learn it is to scrutinize the pre-written code in the template.

However, you can also get a grip on it with [this tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Master/Detail_Flow_Tutorial).

About the second question, go for blob only if you have just a few pictures. But in case you have many pictures, decoding and encoding the pictures can be a pain in the back, so I recommend using simple Drawables.